# Does blacklisting a server prevent quickplay from matching me into a server on my Blacklist?

Tags: team-fortress-2

If I block Server A via my Blacklisted Servers menu will quickplay avoid that server, or does it ignore the Blacklist? I would think it would unless it just stops it from showing up in the server list menu.

Comment: Well I keep getting put onto blacklisted MvM servers, though since that might not be the same system, I'm not going to put this as an answer.